# Multi-row Layout for Workspaces in Metacity

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, workspace, metacity

I'm looking for a way to increase number of rows in worskpaces layout.

i.e. 3 cols and 2 rows. Using `g-conf` I can only change number of worskpaces horizontally, but not vertically, even if it seems to be possibile.

I'm working on a Ubuntu 11.04 machine.

Comment: maybe should be moved to askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. The key to change the number of rows in gconf-editor is
`/apps/panel/applets/workspace_switcher_screen0/prefs/num_rows`
from [Askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42787/how-do-i-enable-multi-row-layout-for-the-workspace-switcher-applet-in-metacity/)

Comment: Is it supposed to work if the workspace switcher applet is not started? I don't have it, and this settings doesn't seem to make any difference.